# Exporting ListView to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, pdf, itext

I am creating an application in which I successfully exported my ListView to PDF format. But I have some problem regarding my PDF: the formatting of the PDF is very bad.

Take a look:

[image]

I am using the following code to export to PDF:

```
protected void ExportToPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string File = "PDFCollegeDetails";
        var result = GetData().ToList();
        ExportListToPDF(result, File);           
    }

    private void ExportListToPDF(List<CollegeDetail> result, string File)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CollegeDetailsInPdf.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.DataSource = result;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50f, 50f, 50f, 50f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using iText? You should mention the specific library you are using.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, i have already mentioned this at the top.

Comment: You are using portrait A4 size pages and draw a 17-column table.... well, what do you expect?

Comment: You can style iTextSharp's output with CSS styles, using the [XML Worker addin](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker)

Comment: Also, the line `Response.Write(pdfDoc);` actually corrupts PDFs and should be removed as it doesn't do what most people thinks it does. Luckily PDFs are forgiving about junk at the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ZoneWiseReport.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridViewZoneReport.AllowPaging = false;
this.BindGridView();
GridViewZoneReport.DataBind();
GridViewZoneReport.RenderControl(hw);
GridViewZoneReport.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
GridViewZoneReport.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
GridViewZoneReport.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
GridViewZoneReport.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
GridViewZoneReport.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```